# OneDrive download session maximum time

Tags: java, rest, onedrive, office365api

I am writing a program which calls OneDrive REST api to download some files (total 12G) using java on the uri:

> GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content

And the inputstream is closed (socket reset from server) before the end of file transfer, causing the file download failed.
I tried to put the same request in chrome and firefox, same problem also appears.

Now I know that I cloud use partial download by adding the `range` header to the http request(and it works like a charm):

> Range: bytes=0-1023

But still, I wonder what is the maximum download time/size that will trigger the close of the connection?

Comment: There's no limit enforced by the service for downloads. How much are you managing to get before it stops? Is it always the same amount or does it vary?

Comment: @Brad the connection terminates after around 30 minutes/ ~1.5G but not a consistent value. Checking the tcp dump, the socket I created hold up for 60seconds (not receiving any data from server although my computer ACK all packets) before it gets timeout and got reset.